# Numpy Array to Graph

Tags: python, numpy, graph

I have a simple 2D Numpy array consisting of 0s and 1s. Is there a simple way to make a graph that will shade in corresponding coordinates?

For example if my array was [[1,0],[0,1]] 
The plot would be a 2x2 square with the top left and bottom right shaded in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) to plot a matrix for you.

Use the [`matshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matshow#matplotlib.pyplot.matshow) command with an appropriate [colourmap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) to produce the plot.

For example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
plt.matshow(x, cmap='Blues')
plt.show()
```

would produce:

[image: matshow example]